# Return object from PowerShell script via WinRM by value, not by reference

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm

I run a PowerShell script via WinRM on a remote machine and I want to get an object out of it (in this case a System.Drawing.Bitmap) to the client machine.
The issue when I just return the object with `Write-Output $obj`, the reference becomes invalid because the object does not exist on the client machine.

So how can I force the script to output the object value (i.e. really transfer the whole data to the client) instead of its reference?

Comment: Copy the bitmap file from the server to client -> `Copy-Item -FromSession $psSessionToServer`. You'll PS 5.x on both machines.

Comment: My client is not PowerShell, it's C# with a Pipeline. Also, my script should output a bitmap every second, and I should get them asynchronously in the Pipeline as soon as each is ready.